# on windows with django i get a WindowsError (3, 'The system cannot find the path specified')

Tags: django

this is particularly at this line:

```
filesys = os.listdir(settings.CAPTCHA_ROOT)
```

it happens when trying to read or write to a directory.

any ideas why it would do this only under Windows?

edit ---------------------------------------

```
 def __clean_captchas(self, offset=3600):
        """docstring for __clean_captchas"""
        filesys = os.listdir(settings.CAPTCHA_ROOT)
        offset = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=offset)
        for file in filesys:
            d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(settings.CAPTCHA_ROOT+file).st_ctime) ...
            if d < offset:
                os.remove(settings.CAPTCHA_ROOT+file)
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out settings.CAPTCHA_ROOT to the log before the crash? That would provide probably the best insight.

Comment: i will have to try this, forgive me if i'm a noob but i'm not sure how to log

Comment: above is the function that cuases the error.. it seems when adding the +file to CAPTCHA_ROOT it raises the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your settings.CAPTCHA_ROOT is incorrect.
For portable paths you should avoid slashes and backslashes and use `os.path.join` function instead, smth. like this:

```
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
CAPTHA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'some','sub','folders')
```

Comment: thanks! it jumped one line and now iget an error at the following line:

for file in filesys:
            d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.stat(settings.CAPTCHA_ROOT+file).st_ctime) ...
            if d < offset:
                os.remove(settings.CAPTCHA_ROOT+file)

Comment: so try using os.path.join(settings.CAPTCH_ROOT, file) instead of settings.CAPTCHA_ROOT+file.

It would also be helpful if you print the value of your settings.CAPTCH_ROOT. Does it have trailing slash?

Comment: Great this works
now i only get an "Access is denied" message when trying os.remove() and i can't get windows to change the permissions. will have to figure this out.. but thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the directory as a constant string, and you're writing the path using backslashes instead of forward slashes, you need to use raw strings. e.g.,

```
CAPTCHA_ROOT = r'D:\captcha'
```